# Upload MySQL database and access on Java application from a remote system

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin, mamp

I recently built a desktop application using Java for the frontend and MySQL for the backend database. Now I want everyone else to be able to use this application too.

So my question is how can I upload my MySQL database online and so that the application can access it remotely? What changes should I make in my  I used MAMP to create and setup this database. The first thing I did was....

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + database, username, password);
```

Then I added a new MySQL user using

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and I also created a my.cnf file and added

```
bind-address = 192.168.1.45
```

Now on the remote system I get the

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your database to be accessed from outside you have to host it to a server, you have the option to do it locally (you have to setup a local server) or using a database cloud service like Azure or Amazon Web Services (AWS).
**Edit:** 
I also found this for you: 
[www.GearHost.com](https://www.gearhost.com/) provides free hosting for both MS SQL and MySQL. The limit on free database MSSQL is 10 MB. 
Source: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-free-SQL-Server-hosting-available

https://aws.amazon.com/free/ that's a service offered by Amazon which lets you host your database for 12 Months for free, after that you'll get charged (or not) depending on the Tier you've chosen.

Comment: By setting up a local server the database will be accessible to systems which are only on the same network right? Are there any free cloud services that I don't need to invest in (since this isn't one of those mainstream projects)?

Comment: I added informationen that may answer this question in the answer, if you find it usefull, accept it as answer by clicking the green check sign.

Comment: Yea I looked into that. Is there anyway I can use wildfly or something?

Comment: Check my edit, I made a little research and found a service that can be a solution for you case since your database is relatively small (I hope so :) )

Comment: Thank you! Does exactly what I needed.